# Nativescript with angular not performing Http Requests

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to perform http requests on my nativescript app, but when call http.get(), I get nothing, no error, no calls into the api.

servicos.component.ts

```
    private servicos: Observable<Servico[]>;

    constructor(
        private servicosService: ServicosService
    ) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
        this.servicos = this.servicosService.listar();

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Init your component properties here.



    }
```

servicos.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ServicosService{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){

    }

    listar(){
        return this.http.get<any>(
            CONSTANTS.SERVER_URL + '/servicos/'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the request, but never subscribing to it! You have a few options here:

1. Subscribe manually and update `servicos`

```
    private servicos: Servico[];

    constructor(
        private servicosService: ServicosService
    ) {
        // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
        this.servicos = this.servicosService.listar().subscribe((response) => this.servicos = response);

    }
```

2. Keep the same code, but use `async` pipes in your html (be careful! it'll call your api every time this screen shows, and will call multiple times for multile `async`s)

```
<Label [text]="servico.text" *ngFor="let servico of servicos | async"></Label>
```

**Context:**

`HttpClient` requests always return `Observable` from `rxjs`.

Observables are cold objects, meaning they do not execute any code until someone `subscribe`s to it. In contrast, `Promise`s always execute at the time it is declared.

Consider the code:

```
const request = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("executing");
    resolve();
});

setTimeout(() => request.then(() => console.log("success")), 1000)
```

Results in

```
executing
- 1s wait -
success
```

Now using `Observable`:

```
const request = new Observable((subscriber) => {
    console.log("executing");
    subscriber.next();
    subscriber.complete();
});

setTimeout(() => request.subscribe(() => console.log("success")), 1000)
```

Results in:

```
- 1s wait -
executing
success
```

The `async` pipe essentially calls `subscribe` when it's "rendered" and `unsubscribe` when destroyed, so you don't have to manage it yourself.